# Strange SQL Cursor behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

`enter code here`I have a cursor (marinating old code) like this:

```
DECLARE MYCursor  CURSOR FOR
SELECT ANumber,CNumber,Login_Name,S_Date,
 FROM MyTable 
 ORDER BY ANumber, S_Date
```

When I run only the SQL

```
SELECT ANumber,CNumber,Login_Name,S_Date,
     FROM MyTable 
     ORDER BY ANumber, S_Date
```

I get data as expected with older dates on the top.

When I run the cursor I get all rows but put newer dates on the top. That is cursor return items in the reverse order.

---

I removed ANumber  from  `Order By`

Still I see results in reverse order:

This is my complete code:

```
DECLARE @ANubmer as  Varchar(100)
DECLARE @BNumber as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @Login_Name as Varchar(100)
DECLARE @S_Date as datetime

 DECLARE MYCursor  CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ANumber,BNumber,Login_Name,S_Date,Evaluator_ID,Evaluator_Date
     FROM MyTable 
     ORDER BY  S_Date 

OPEN MyCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @ANubmer, @BNumber,@Login_Name,@S_DT,@Evaluator_ID,@Evaluator_Date

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

IF @Login_Name='ABC'
    BEGIN
            IF @Evaluator_ID is null AND @Evaluator_Date is null     
            UPDATE tblb
            SET Evaluator_ID=@Login_Name,
                Evaluator_Date=@S_DT
            WHERE ACIDNumber=@ACIDNumber            
    END


FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @ANubmer, @BNumber,@Login_Name,@S_DT,@Evaluator_ID,@Evaluator_Date

END

CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

The core logic is if `evaluator_Date` in `mytable` is null, update

> `tblb` with the **earliest**  `S_Date`.

`tblb` Gets updates with dates but with reverse order!

After this runs values go into tblb But not the way they are expected:

For example If following values are in MyTable:

```
 ANumber BNumber Login_Name S_Date        Evaluator_id   Evaluator_Date
  1        2       ABC       1/11/2015      Null           Null

  1        2       ABC       1/12/2015      Null           Null
```

tblB will be poupalted as :

```
ANumber BNumber Login_Name S_Date        Evaluator_id   Evaluator_Date
      1        2       ABC       1/12/2015      ABC         1/12/2015
```

Comment: The dates should be neither at the top nor bottom.  The first key for the sort is `ANumber`.  Perhaps you are running the cursor and code on different databases that have different content.

Comment: Show us the different results. (Just enough rows to describe...)

Comment: They are sorted by Anumber Then Date. Cursor doe not sort by date correctly

Comment: Do `ANumber` and `S_Date`, taken together, *uniquely* specify the order in which rows should appears (i.e. are there no rows with the same values in both columns), if not, then provided the server is returning rows with *those* columns correctly sorted, it's acting correctly.

Comment: Still, show us some different output from the two cases!

Comment: Is it possible that in the code after cursor definition you call `FETCH LAST` and then `FETCH PRIOR` reversing order of SQL ?

Comment: In your code you declare `MyCursor` but open `SurveyCursor`

Comment: it was a typo. corrected

Comment: Your question makes no sense -- you use a column name and a variable name that are not defined in your example data and code `WHERE ACIDNumber=@ACIDNumber`  Both `ACIDNumber` and `@ACIDNumber` are not defined anywhere.  In any case since you don't update `@ACIDNumber` in your FETCH you are making changes to only one row.

Comment: why are you using a cursor at all for this?

Comment: @ HLGEM What is your suggestion?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you still haven't managed to work it out, try inserting the select into a temporary table first with an Order By clause.

`SELECT DATA1, DATA2
 INTO #TEMP_TABLE
 FROM ORG_TABLE
 ORDER BY 1, 2`

So with this temp table order, declare your cursor:

```
DECLARE MYCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT ANumber, CNumber, Login_Name, S_Date
FROM #TEMP_TABLE
```

Comment: Why you think a temp table help here?

Comment: I just thought it would help, sorry for that.